# Will Expo notifications work after project is built?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, notifications, expo

I am building a React Native app with Expo, and I am using [Expo Notifications](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/).

If I go to build this app on iOS and Android, will Expo Notifications still work on the built app? Or is this something that only works so long as the app runs on Expo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get Expo push notifications to work on standalone apps you must follow Expo's documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/). This will walk you through getting push notifications working on standalone app with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

**NOTE:** FCM is not currently available for Expo iOS apps.

Comment: What do I use as an alternative to FCM since it's not available on ios?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Yes.

It's just a library after all, and requires installation in both workflows.

[It might be worth re-visiting the concepts and architecture of Expo](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/), and understanding how it all works. But I can anecdotally state that it works after build.

Was there a reason you suspected it wouldn't?

Comment: I was just making sure it would still work as it's a very important part to our project. Thanks.